# What is the default port that is assigned when OWIN hosting a web api?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I created a owin hosted web api application without specifying a port. The url I have is like below.

http://{My machine name}/api/v1/SomeController/SomeAction

Everything works for me in this case and I am able to hit the action in my required controller. But I am curious what does the port default to in this case? Would it be port 80 similar to IIS? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http` always defaults to `80`,
`https` always defaults to `443` unless u specify a port explicitly.

You can go ahead and read [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/233383/why-was-80-chosen-as-the-default-http-port-and-443-as-the-default-https-port/) to know why they are chosen as defaults! :)

Happy Coding!